# How to sort a 2d String array using java?

Tags: java, arrays

I've created a deck of cards using enum and ArrayList, converted the ArrayList to an array using the following code:

```
private void listToArray(ArrayList<PlayingCard> cardList, PlayingCard[] cardArray)
{
    cardArray = cardList.toArray(cardArray);
}
```

Then I moved on to transfer the object array into a string array:

```
private void transfer(PlayingCard[] cardArray, String[] strArray)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < strArray.length; k ++)
    {
        strArray[k] = cardArray[k].toString(); 
    }
 }
```

Now I would like to sort the output of my cards using 13columns and 4rows, however, I encountered ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with the sort2D method I have.

```
private void transfer2D(String[][] twoD, String[] strArray)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < this.rows ; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < this.MAXC; b++)
        {
            twoD[a][b] = strArray[(a*(twoD[a].length)+b];
        }
    }

}
private void sort2D(String[][] twoD)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < twoD.length ; c++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d < twoD.length - 1; d++)
        {
            if(twoD[d][this.MAXC].compareTo(twoD[d + 1][this.MAXC]) > 0)
            {
                String[] tempArray = new String[twoD[d].length];
                tempArray = twoD[d];
                twoD[d] = twoD[d + 1];
                twoD[d+1] = tempArray;
            }
        }
    }
}
private void print2D(String[][] strArray)
{
    for (int e = 0; e < strArray.length; e++)
    {
        System.out.println(strArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: And you don't want to sort the initial list `ArrayList<PlayingCard> cardList`? Would be way easier.

Comment: I applied the shuffle method as well, hence the 2d string array to represent a each hand, so now I wan to sort the cards in each hand

Comment: If the whole exercise is not about getting acquainted with arrays, I'd propose not to use them, one gets crazy with the indexing stuff, as you already found out. Collections(Lists) provide a [sort method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-sort-java-examples/) too, and all the stream() machinery.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
for (int d = 0; d < twoD.length - 1; d++)
```

To this:

```
for (int d = 0; d < twoD[c].length - 1; d++)
```

Then it will work.

Comment: ... and then? Did it work? Is that your proposed answer to OPs question? Please read [answer].

Comment: thanks for your help, I have already applied the method you provided and my program is working now :)